# How do I set up a Python web-scraping Script on my server?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I built a web-scraper in Python using the requests module. It reads and writes to text files every so often. I'm trying to put the script on a server and have it automatically post data to my website. Its my understanding that web apps start a new instance of Python every time they are accessed, this isn't what I'm after. I am trying to have one instance of my Python script run and then post data to my site for whoever is on it.

I looked into Heroku but I could not figure out how to use their platform on my own. I have a hunch that something like this can be done with AWS, but I don't know how.

This is the type of script I'm trying to run on my server:

```
# This is an oversimplification of my web-scraper, but its basically what it does.
import time
import requests

def update_doc(doc_path, doc_text, command):
    doc = open(doc_path, command)
    doc.write(str(doc_text))
    doc.close()

while True:
    r = requests.get(url)
    if new_data in url:
        print('New data found.')  # But instead of printing it updates my site
        update_doc(path, r.text, 'w')
    time.sleep(60)
```

I didn't paste my whole script into this question as I didn't really think it was relevant. I'm mainly just asking how I would put a script like this onto my website, and have it update a webpage on my site without me having to hit "F5".

I purchased a domain on NameCheap and have access to my own cPanel, but I'm not sure this is the the way I'm supposed to do something like this. Could someone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score -1):

You can run this on heroku, look into their worker pricing and having a persistent node for your app so it doesn't have to restart every so often.

This is pretty off topic though.

https://bigishdata.com/2016/12/15/running-python-background-jobs-with-heroku/

https://www.heroku.com/pricing

or try celery

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/celery-heroku

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? The Heroku documentation is kind of confusing. It also doesn't mention how data would go from a Python script to a website.

Comment: You would be hosting your app or website on heroku.  You can communicate between your script and your website logic in a variety of ways. You may want to look into a framework for python to handle some parts of that for you. I would suggest researching more on the structure of websites and how you can send data between scripts you run on your server and your website code.

Comment: Well. Yea, I know I would have to research on structures of websites and how to send data, that's what I'm opening this thread to ask about.

Comment: Try tutorials for something like flask or django, look into heroku tutorials since you want to use that hosting service. It will help to try things out and see how things work with those tutorials.